# How to compare child categories in WordPress?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, parent-child

On my page a have one of many parent categories called "people". It has some child categories like "professor" or "doctor", etc. In this child categories I have specific people as  2nd order child categories. 
I have also a parent category called "teaching", where seminars and related stuff are listed. the teaching posts are also given the teachers category (amongst others)

Now my problem: If I open the specific page of a person (person is also a custom post type) it is in the categories: people->position->The person itself. I want to show in a sidebar a list of the teachings of that person.

I tried to design a small widget in my themes functions.php but I don't know how to read out the category ID of the person itself (which is a 2nd order child category of person->position), and to compare it to the person-ID, I have given the teachings.

And to be honest no clue how to achieve that, since the teachings is in more categories than one and the teacher itself a 2nd order child category...

Right now I use this code. It works partially, but not completely. Sometimes some teachings are skipped for no reason, I am able to understand:

```
$categories=get_the_category(); 
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $name = $cat->name;
    $fullname[] = $name;

}
wp_reset_query();

$people_title = get_the_title();
$loop = new WP_Query( array ('cat' => '293') );
    echo '<ul class="own_widget">';
        echo sizeof($fullname);
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fullname); $i++) {
            if (in_category($fullname[$i])) {echo '<li class="own_widget_item">'.get_the_title().'</li>';} 
        }   

        endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';   wp_reset_query();
```

What approach can I try next?

Comment: Create a widget or page template? And try to use this: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/

Comment: that only shows the parent and the 1st order child category, in my case: People>>Position. But I need the 2nd order child: parent>>position>>NAME